# What happens if your Windows or Office Open License expires?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

We have 10 copies of Office 2007 that we purchased about 2 years ago on a Microsoft Open License (no Software Assurance). I recently got an email from Microsoft saying my agreement would expire in 90 days and to renew soon.

I thought purchasing the open license meant I "owned" the license perpetually but it looks like I was mistaken. Do I need to renew this agreement? Should I renew this license?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the specific license that you purchased. Some are subscriptin based. Part of the renewal may include stuff like Software Assurance etc.

I would suggest an actual telephone call to MS to make sure. Speak to a person from MS to get details about your specific contracts. You can ask them all sorts of questions. If you did not get a perpetual license, then this might be the oportunity to ask about how you could get it and get financing. Ignoring this if you did not have a perpetual license essential means you are setting yourself up for an expensive audit!

Getting advice from the net and who do not know what contracts you signed can lead you into a whole bunch of legl trouble.

Comment: I ended up calling Microsoft. The licenses are good even when the agreement expires. The agreement expiring didn't have any implications from MSFT's point of view, but they told me to talk to my reseller (CDW) if I need to make any changes to the expired agreement (add new licenses for example).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you don't need to renew to continue using the software you've already licensed but you do need to renew to take advantage of software assurance, upgrades, etc.